# Contar registros duplicados en las columna

Tags: mysql, sql

No sé si puedo explicar lo que quiero, pero tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Año  | Primero | Segundo | Tercero
2021     11        13        44
2021     34        21        11
2021     11        34        13
```

Los números serán aleatorios y del 1 al 99. Me gustaría contar los números totales en las columna. Ejemplo:

```
Número 11: 3
Número 13: 2
Número 34: 2
```

¿Es posible hacer esto con SQL usando MySQL? El lenguaje de programación que estoy usando es PHP. Intenté usar COUNT ():

```
SELECT COUNT(Primero) AS P, COUNT(Segundo) AS S, COUNT(Tercero) AS T FROM tabela;
```

Pero no creo que ese sea el caso, ya que traería el recuento total de la tabla y no los registros que necesito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es unir las tres columnas en una sola y recién ahí contar las cantidades de cada valor:

```
SELECT T.Valor, 
       COUNT(1) as Cantidad
       FROM (SELECT Primero As Valor
                    FROM  tabela
             UNION ALL
             SELECT Segundo As Valor
                    FROM  tabela
             UNION ALL
             SELECT TerceroAs Valor
                    FROM  tabela
       ) T
       GROUP BY T.Valor
```

El `group by` se aplica a una subconsulta dónde unimos todas los valores de cada fila  mediante el `union all`.

Comment: Perfecto, Patricio. Funcionó. Muchas gracias.